# Resizing a Texture2D without Draw

Tags: c#, xna, textures

As the title states, I'm trying to resize a `Texture2D` before even considering `SpriteBatch.Draw()`.  The reason I'm doing this is I'm trying to fill an arbitrary polygon, laid out with vertices defined by `Vector2D`s, with an arbitrary `Texture2D`.

What I'm thinking of is creating the rectangle that fits the polygon, scaling the `Texture2D` to that rectangle, and then making the pixels that are outside of the polygon transparent via `Texture2D`'s `GetData<>()` and `SetData<>()`.

I've gotten to the point of finding the rectangle that fits the polygon, but is there a way to resize the `Texture2D`, or am I going about it the completely wrong way?  Thanks!

Comment: If you are scaling, then the texture2d will automatically scale when you pass your arguments to Draw. Your Texture2D should remain the same in memory, your drawing should transform the texture

Comment: Keep in mind that it's probably a bad idea to use the CPU to scale it (like you intend to do it). The `Draw()` method overloads for example use the GPU for that. I guess there is also a way to use a blending mask to trim the outsides of the polygon away using only minimal CPU resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going about it the wrong way. Setting texture data is expensive. (And there's probably some issues with filtering, too.)

What you want to do is set the **texture coordinates** (the "UV coordinates") of the vertices you are drawing. This will cause a specific location of your texture to appear at that vertex of your polygon. The texture that would then fall outside your polygon is simply never drawn (it is "clipped" by the polygon edges).

Texture coordinates are specified in the range 0.0 to 1.0 (on the U and V axies - horizontally and vertically) from the top left to the bottom right of your texture.

If you are drawing using vertex buffers, XNA includes some built-in vertex structures like `VertexPositionTexture` and `VertexPositionColorTexture` that allow you to specify a `TextureCoordinate` value.

If you are using your own vertex structure, use `VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate` when specifying a `VertexElement`. If you are creating your own shader, the value will be exposed in `TEXCOORD0` (for usage index 0).

---

If you are just drawing rectangles with `SpriteBatch`, then specify a `sourceRectangle` when you call `Draw`.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because, although it didn't give me everything I needed, it ended up being what I used.  I had to do a bunch of research to finally get it to work, though. :P

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should be using the overloads on the Draw method (I realise you are for some reason not wanting to do this, but it's like this for a good reason):

```
public void Draw (
     Texture2D texture,
     Vector2 position,
     Nullable<Rectangle> sourceRectangle,
     Color color,
     float rotation,
     Vector2 origin,
     Vector2 scale,
     SpriteEffects effects,
     float layerDepth
)
```

The sourceRectangle, scale parameter, and origin should be enough. Don't modify the texture in memory, it's relatively expensive to do this (especially doing it every frame!)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb196420(v=xnagamestudio.31).aspx

Can you explain why you don't want to scale in Draw()?

Comment: I may just not be understanding things properly, but basically what I want is a new texture.  I'm trying to crop out the parts of the texture that won't be included in the polygon, but I can't do that if the texture is smaller or larger than the polygon.  I won't be doing it every frame.  I'm just doing it in the constructor.  I'll try to post a visual example of what I want.

Comment: I think I understand what you want, but why are you trying to do it? Is there an issue with just using the full texture but having bits of it not drawn? Scale it up to the polygons bounding box size and set the origin to 0,0 and the scale to the extends of the bounding box

Comment: I don't follow.  How do I make the pixels outside the polygon not show up.  And sorry, I'm new to XNA.  I'm probably trying to do things all the wrong ways.

Comment: Yeah sorry I'm being stupid, completely forgot about SpriteBatch only drawing rects - and I see what you are trying to do now. Have you considered using the 3D drawing plane but drawing in parallel projection? You can draw whatever shape you want using this, check out this forum post, it's also got a link off the original article: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/49472/297403.aspx

Comment: Okay, I'm trying it out, but it's saying the Effect class doesn't have any of the properties/methods that are in the example.